# how to filter the combobox values in vb

Tags: combobox

I am new to VB.I have a policy no. combobox in VB which populates after I enter first four digits of the policy no.However, if I continue to type the number it overwrites what I have already typed and wipes out the dropdown list, as if selecting for the new 4 numbers I typed.I Want to acheive a scenario where I will enter the first 4 numbers to populate the dropdown after that as i go on entering the policyno the values in the dropdown list get searched.

E.G:Policy number: 969003648, as I type 9690 the drop down is filled in with the policy no's starting from 969000001, now as I go on typing the values as 969003 etc the searched values gets limited to the policy no's having 969003 as starting values...Please assist

My code:

```
Private Sub PolicyNo_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = 46 Or KeyCode = 8 Then
Me.PolicyNo.value = ""
Else

If Len(Me.PolicyNo.Text) >= 4  Then
Me.PolicyNo.RowSource = ""
Call ReloadPolicyNo(Nz(Me.PolicyNo.Text, ""))

Function ReloadPolicyNo(sPolicyNo As String)

Me.PolicyNo.RowSource = "SELECT Inventory.PolicyNo FROM Inventory " & _
                          "WHERE Left(Inventory.PolicyNo," & Len(Me.PolicyNo.Text) & ")  = '" & Me.PolicyNo.Text & "' order by Inventory.PolicyNo"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Textchanged event on your combo box to get what is currently in the combobox ?

Example

```
    'THIS FIRES WHEN TEXT IS ENTERED INTO THE COMBOBOX
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged

    'GET VALUE IN COMBOBOX
    Dim enteredText As String = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim strSelect As String = "select * from table where field like = '" & enteredText & "'%"

    'load COMBO BOX HERE

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `DataView` here , I declared `DataTable` as `class Variable`.

```
Dim dt as DataTable
```

Fetched All the data from database and bind it to declared `DataTable`, This `DataTable` further added to `DataView` and use `RowFilter` to filter `DataView`. 
 `Compay_Type` is one of the column in my `DataTable` Below code will filter `DataView` and bind data where column `Company_Type=1`

```
            Dim dvComp As New DataView(dt)
            dvComp.RowFilter = "Company_Type=1"
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CompanyName"
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "CompanyID"
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dvComp
```

To remove Filter just use `dvComp.RowFilter = Nothing`

Comment: Have you downvoted my answer? Did you find my honesty hurtful because you are used to deal with dishonest people attacking others behind their backs? What should I do with your answer now? It is objectively wrong because of not addressing what the OP is asking; it isn't even well formatted (no time for that, but plenty of time for visiting 4-year-old-questions to bother others). It deserves a downvote, but I will not do it. I rarely downvote (non-constructive, usually arbitrary and coward attack); additionally and precisely thanks to attitudes like yours, I don't contribute to SO anymore.