# How to filter my combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have managed to filter my combobox so it filters and displays the correct records ie when A is typed all A records show, B is typed all B records show and so on.  However it would it be possible to have a message box to display when no records is found in the combobox?

The coding i have so far is :-

```
  Private Sub cmblogged_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cmblogged.KeyPress
        If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then Return

        With Me.cmblogged

            Dim ToFind As String = .Text.Substring(0, .SelectionStart) & e.KeyChar
            Dim Index As Integer = .FindStringExact(ToFind)

            If Index = -1 Then Index = .FindString(ToFind)
            If Index = -1 Then Return

            .SelectedIndex = Index
            .SelectionStart = ToFind.Length
            .SelectionLength = .Text.Length - .SelectionStart

            e.Handled = True

        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving what you want with your code is straightforward, just convert `If Index = -1 Then Return` into:

```
 If Index = -1 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Not Found.")
     Return
 End If
```

In any case, note that there is an in-built functionality in `ComboBox` performing the same action which your code does right now: `AutoCompleteMode` different than `None` and `AutoCompleteSource` set to `ListItems`. Logically, you can evolve your code to perform much more complex actions (what I guess that is the case), but I preferred to highlight this issue just in case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, with your help I have partially resolved the problem but would be ever greatful if you could offer just a bit of more help.  When i use the coding once it finds an invalid character and the message box displays it removes all fields and shows the last invalid character but i only want to remove the last character?  For example if my combobox contains a field of "orange" and i enter "Orant" the message box appears and after the message box it should say "Oran" but it says "t" why would it do this?  Many thanks about the functions I will look at this.

Comment: @JackSparrow I dont have the VS with me now and cannot check it. But you can delete the last input character by affecting the selectedtext property; bear in mind that it might even not have been written yet depending upon the event you are in. The safest option is doing everything from the keyup/mouseup events, you might put all your code in any of those methods. If you cannot figure it out by yourself I will help you further tomorrow.

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje?! What has this to do with what was asked (+ answered + accepted) almost 4 years ago? Your answer (not trying to offend, but not precisely a marvellous answer) refers to getting the ComboBox items from a datasource and the OP here isn't even concerned about this issue (perhaps the items are hardcoded in the GUI part or other not-compatible with your proposal alternative), just asking about an error message box. BTW, do you have anything to with a pretty arbitrary downvote which I got yesterday in another VB.NET answer? Please, don't waste people's time with nonsense.

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje Regarding the aforementioned downvote, note that I deleted that answer. This is my usual reaction to the kind of pathetic (and usually extremely-ignorant) arbitrary downvotes. In fact, this (+ having to deal with "people" doing such things) was the main reason why I stopped answering questions in SO. This is a message to help whoever performs this kind of actions (you or another person) know what they provoke (other than making me feel pity): me not helping anyone else + continue deleting my past contributions. This is the prize that stupidity and fanaticism gets from me.

Comment: For those wondering who is this self-invited-4-year-later fellow and the answer which he thought that was relevant here (because he has gone one step further in his brave and sensible attitude by downvoting this answer and deleting his comment), feel free to take a look at this "piece of art" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511442/how-to-filter-the-combobox-values-in-vb/43772640#43772640) not even addressing what the OP is asking. See the reason for my initial aggressiveness? I can sense these "people" miles away and want to help them understand why they shouldn't be dealing with me.